# $value++ will not add 1 for me in php

Tags: php, html, for-loop, foreach

Here is my code..

```
<?php
$files = scandir('audio');
$files = array_slice($files, 2);
$files = array_combine(range(1, count($files)), $files);
foreach ($files as $file) {
$count =0;
echo ++$count . " ";
echo rtrim($file, ".mp3 ");
{ ?>    
<br><audio src="audio/<?php echo rtrim($file, " "); ?>" controls="controls"></audio><br>
<?php }  
echo "<hr>"; 
}
?>
```

Part of that code is

```
$count =0;
echo ++$count . " ";
```

As I currently have 4 files in my directory, I was expecting this to echo `1,2,3,4` but instead I got `1,1,1,1`

I have also tried the other way round with `$count++` (for post/pre) but this gives me `0,0,0,0` what am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: ```$count =0; <---------------
echo ++$count . " ";``` You are initializing count to zero. every. time. **Move it out of your for loop.**

Comment: you reset $count to zero every time you start the loop

Comment: If I move it out of the loop then It won't add 1 for every file it finds in the loop? I think i must be approaching this wrong, I need a new "echo-able" number for each file it finds in the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your count variable out of the for loop:

```
$count =0;
foreach ($files as $file) {
  echo ++$count . " ";
  echo rtrim($file, ".mp3 ");
 }
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, make perfect sense now, when the others were saying "you reset $count to zero every time you start the loop" and "You are initializing count to zero. every. time." (before the edit to add "Move it out of your for loop.") I was not understanding but now i get exactly what they were trying to say. :-)

Comment: @GlenKeybit - since my answer helped you, please mark it as such.

Comment: Yes no problem, I did try to at the time but I had to wait till it allowed me to.